# Xcode 6.3 and 6.2 issue : Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I can't run the application on iPhone 6 or 4s either with Xcode 6.2 or 6.3.

[image]

[image]

[image: I can't press the deoplyment target]

Comment: is the iphone running iOS 8.2?

Comment: I don't think xcode 6.2 supports lower OSs.. don't know which work exactly though .. 6.3b is is iOS 8.2 only IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other user suggested, select your target from the left sidebar. Then click on General and change the deployment target of your project.

By the way, if you are using Swift please not that Swift doesn't run on iOS versions lower than 7.

[image]
<sub>(source: [raywenderlich.com](https://cdn4.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Deployment-target.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Change the deployment target of the project settings.

Comment: I can't check the image